# Security with redactor.js - is there such tutorial for ruby/rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wysiwyg, redactor

[Security code for PHP](http://imperavi.com/redactor/docs/security/)

I'm trying to find same tutorial for ruby enviroment.

May be someone knows one?

Answer (score 1):

Security on this level (as mentioned in article) is built into Rails so deeply you don't even have to think about it. You can read more in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html)

Just to mention one of the features highlighted in the article - referrer checking (it makes me laugh someone want's to secure app in such a way)
In Rails, to secure possibly destructible requests (POST, GET and DELETE) we use authenticity token. It is a one use string that get's saved in session when a form is generated and allows to verify that user actually displayed the form before performing a request.

(I know a good answer should be more elaborate but I don't think it makes sense to copypaste Guides here...)